Prove that the supremum of $\int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx$ is $1$.
I consider the set $E=\{f\in C^0([0,1],\mathbb{R}) : 0\leq f\leq 1, f(0)=0\}$
and I want to show that the supremum of $\int_{0}^{1}f(x)\mathrm dx$ over $E$ is $1$.
First it is easy to see that for all $f\in E$ we have that $\int_{0}^{1}f(x)\mathrm dx\leq 1$. Now I want to find a sequence of functions $(f_n)_n\subset E$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{0}^{1}f_n(x)\mathrm dx=1$. My candidate sequence is the following : $f_n(x) = 1-(1-x)^n$,each $f_n$ is continuous as the sum of two continuous functions, clearly $0\leq f_n(x)\leq 1$ for all $x\in[0,1]$ and all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $f_n(0) = 1-1^n = 0$. Since $\int_{0}^{1}1-(1-x)^n\mathrm  dx = [x + \frac{(1-x)^{n+1}}{n+1}]_{x=0}^{x=1}=1-\frac{1}{n+1}$ we conclude that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{0}^{1}f_n(x)\mathrm dx=1$.
I would like to know if my proof is correct and also, if you have an other way to prove it using another sequence or another characterization of the supremum please.
Thank you a lot

Looks good to me!

Nice choice of $(f_n)$!

Thank you for your feedback !

Yes, your answer seems perfectly correct.
In fact, you proved a stronger statement as, if you pay attention, your functions are even $\mathcal{C}^\infty$...
If you want a different sequence of function to compare, I would have used the much uglier sequence of continuous function:
$f_n(x) = n x$ if $x<\frac{1}{n}$ and $1$ if not...
It's a much uglier sequence. But hopefully you can see it is sort of "easier to think of".
But anyway, rest assured. Yours is better, so congratulations.

I did not realize that they are $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}$, thank you a lot for your detailed answer !

You could also have use $f_n(x)=\sqrt[n]x$. In fact, since $f_n(x)\le 1$ and $f_{n+1}(x)\ge f_n(x)$, intuitively $f_n(x)$ approaches to $1$:
$$\int_0^1  \sqrt[n]x\mathrm dx=\int_0^1 x^{1/n}\mathrm dx=\frac{x^{\frac1n+1}}{\frac1n+1}\Bigg|_0^1=\frac n{n+1}\to 1$$


Did not think of this choice of $(f_n)_n$ at all, thank you !
